# How to sort a table each time I add rows

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

         var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
         var element1 = document.createElement("input");
         element1.type = "checkbox";
         element1.name = "chk[]";
         cell1.appendChild(element1);

         var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
         var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

         cell2.innerHTML = arrSchmCode[1];

         rowCount = rowCount + 1;
```

i want to sort the table based on the value of cell2.

Comment: Show your full code. Which type of `object` **table** is?

Comment: var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

Comment: Check thi out [Sorting an HTML table with JavaScript](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37632/sorting-an-html-table-with-javascript)

Comment: You need to clearly show your code for us to help. Your comment says `dataTable`? Are you trying to use jquery `dataTable` plug-in and struggling to get it to work properly?